# Do not create rendering for a template during jss deploy

Tags: jss

I am using Sitecore 9.3 Instance with JSS.

I need to create a component that consists of 2 templates - say - Template1.sitecore.js and Template2.sitecore.js and 1 rendering - RenderingName/index.js.

So that, when I deploy it using `jss deploy app` command, only one json rendering is created in sitecore/Layouts/Renderings/ folder.

I am able to achieve it in Sitecore 9.2 by adding parameter - `createRendering : false` in Template2.sitecore.js, so that it does not create a component corresponding to that one. See code below -

```
import { CommonFieldTypes, SitecoreIcon, Manifest } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-manifest';

export default function(manifest) {
  manifest.addComponent({
    name: 'Template2',
    icon: SitecoreIcon.DocumentTag,
    fields: [
    { name: 'title', type: CommonFieldTypes.SingleLineText,displayName:'Title' , section: 'Data' },
{ name: 'description', type: CommonFieldTypes.RichText,displayName:'Description' , section: 'Data' },
    ],
createRendering: false,

allowedPlaceholders: ['jss-main'],

  });
}
```

This worked for Sitecore 9.2 but when I use it in Sitecore 9.3, it creates a component for Template2.

Can anybody please suggest why it is not working in Sitecore 9.3 and how to resolve this?

Comment: Is there any issue if you create Template2 separately using manifest.addTemplate or this doesn't fit your requirement.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to create an additional template Template2 then you may try the below,

Add below file "Template2.sitecore.js" under "\sitecore\definitions\templates".

```
import { CommonFieldTypes } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-manifest'

export default function (manifest) {
  manifest.addTemplate({
    name: 'Template2',
    fields: [
      { name: 'title', type: CommonFieldTypes.SingleLineText,displayName:'Title' , section: 'Data' },
  { name: 'description', type: CommonFieldTypes.RichText,displayName:'Description' , section: 'Data' },
      ],
  })
}
```

Comment: Yup. This worked. Thanks!